# Calling a void method from another class Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to call this method from class Student, my student class is linked to my Library, TextBook and LibraryCard class.

My Student class:

```
   private ArrayList<Student> students;
    private Library collegeLib;
    private Random randomNum;
```

My Student constructor:

```
public Student(String name, Library library)
{
    // initialise instance variables
    studentName = name;
    studentJoin = library;
    studentCard = studentJoin.issueCard();
    studentBookBorrowed = null;

}
```

and the method i'm trying to call:

```
 public void study()
    {
        if((studentBookBorrowed == null))
        {
            studentJoin.borrowBook(studentCard);

        }
        else if(!studentBookBorrowed.isFinished())
        {
            studentBookBorrowed.readNextChapter();                
        }
        else
        {
            studentBookBorrowed.closeBook();
            studentJoin.returnBook(studentBookBorrowed);
            studentBookBorrowed= null;

        }

    }
```

In my class College, which i'm trying to call the method in I have done:

```
private void study(Student student)
    {
     student.study();   
    }
```

and then tried to call the method, study();.

This is the error i'm getting:

Method study in COllege cannot be applied to given types: required: Student; found no arguments. Arguments lists differ in length..

if I try to call the method by doing: Student.study(); i get the error: non-static method study() cannot be referenced from static context.

I cannot change my study() method to static since my lecture doesn't want it in that way.

**My attempt of trying to call the method in College**

```
  private void nextStep(){
 ....
  else
       {

        study();
       }
 }      


private void study(Student student)
{
 student.study();   
}
```

Comment: Post the Car class code and the complete error message.

Comment: To help us now and to help yourself in the future, please learn and use standard Java naming conventions: class names all start with an upper-case letter and method/variable names with a lower-case letter.

Comment: What is the purpose of the car.BMW(); method? What does it do? Try to be more descriptive when naming your methods, "BMW" doesn't really explain what is the purpose of it.

Comment: This video helps you how to code in Java. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SSmB_HA0edc

Comment: Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We can't rely on code you don't post.

Comment: I read this question many times, but I just couldn't understand what OP wants to ask.

Comment: I'm so sorry, a typo!

Comment: @Vari3ty You are confusing yourself by creating methods at the wrong place. Why are you creating study() method in Student class and College class. What is study() supposed to do? Can you give a more meaningful method name for your methods?

Comment: I would, however the coursework brief i was assigned clearly states to call the method this name and constructing the constructor.  Study() is a method ,that  if the student doesn't have a book it will force the student to borrow a book from the library. If they have a book and it is not finished then they read the next chapter of the book. Otherwise, they have finished the book and returned it back to the library . The number of books they borrowed is then set back to 0/null.

Comment: You're not showing how you try to call College's `study(...)` method.

Comment: The method signature of `College#study` is `study(Student)`, so you said you will pass a `Student` instance when you call this method, but here `study();` you're calling it without any argument. Does this make sense to you?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels It was from a question which was on hold. I think that question was removed minutes ago. Thanks a lot for looking into it though.

Comment: @user3437460: for what it's worth, 1+ to your answer. You guessed correctly, and 1+ to this question as the original poster is sincerely trying to improve it.

Answer (score 2):

This error from your compiler says it all:

> Method study in COllege cannot be applied to given types: required: Student; found no arguments. Arguments lists differ in length..

I am pretty sure when you invoke your study method (from your College class), you miss out the method arguments.

Method signature of study() from College class:

```
study(Student s)
```

You should do:

```
College c = new College();
Student s = new Student();
c.study(s);
```

You probably did:

```
c.study();  //Missing arguments
```